# Make two JList scroll simultaneously

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have two instances of JList currently, one being `priceList` and the other is the `nameList`. When they are scrolling, I want them to scroll together, because they are side by side. Currently, the only one I can find is to make them highlight the same index result when the user selects, using this code.

```
priceList.setSelectedIndex(nameList.getSelectedIndex());
priceList.ensureIndexIsVisible(nameList.getSelectedIndex());
```

Is there any other viable ways?

Comment: *"I have two JListBox"*  Unless you are referring to a 3rd party component, I am guessing you have 2 instances of `JList` or `JComboBox`. 1) Which is it? 2) Don't be so sloppy in future.  Copy/paste when in doubt, as it will save us all a lot of guessing.

Comment: Sorry, yes, i mean i have 2 instances of JList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try attaching the BoundRangeModel from the scroll panes scroll bars & apply it o other.

```
BoundedRangeModel model = scrollPane1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel();
scrollPane2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(model);
```

This should cause the two scroll bars to update each other automatically

Comment: i tried using your code but there are two issues. 1) i'm using NetBeans and isn't quite sure where to insert the codes. 2) I tried adding your snippet of code to nameListMouseWheelMoved. Not sure if i'm doing it right. Please advice!

Comment: from the code snippet, the @Jieqin seems to want the selection synched as well. If so, additionally share the selection model.

Comment: @kleopatra I had taken that as the solution he'd implemented, but your point is valid

Comment: @Jieqin try adding the code after the initComponent method in the constructor, it's to late (& over kill) to do so in the event handler. You could also override the addNotify method to register the listeners & removeNotify to unregister them

Answer (score 0):

Put both JLists into a single JPanel.

Then put the JPanel in a JScrollPane.

Or else, put the information in a JTable.